# CSS - Font not displayed at customer IE11

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-11

We are using a font from fonts.com for our client http://www.forstinger.com. Since recently at our customers headquarter the font is not being displayed correctly. We are using a bought font from fonts.com. It looks ok on all our browsers, except at the customers.

This only affects the Navigation and Teaser elements on the page. The CSS is implemented like this:

```
.menu li a span{float:left; height:38px; padding-right:15px; font:normal 20px/38px 'FranklinITCW01-CnMedium 731417',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color:#000000; }
```

I read something about max length for fonts in IE, but it´s working ok on my machine. I´m stuck here and I got no idea how to fix this.

Comment: step 1: fix problems flagged in console. http://imgur.com/cuVxNtA